# GMAP use the google satellite layer

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmap.net

I used in my Windows application(C#) GMAP API, I need to show the terrine feature of the map hence, I try to asssign the provider of the map as follow:

```
 Map.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleSatelliteMap;
```

unfortunately, the map didn't appear and show error as following:

[image]

How to get satellite view in C#??

Answer (score 3):

check if you are in :
this is offline mode, it results to that if there are no caches.

> GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.CacheOnly;

if your map's zoom property is in 0, it will result to that. do this.

> MainMap.Zoom=5;    //country level zoom

EDIT: another thing, this is the code to view in satellite map.

> MainMap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;

Answer (score 1):

Try Newer Greatmap Release in Map

Answer (score 0):

You should download the lastest version of GMap.Net from here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/GMap.NET.Presentation/